# How to write apple script that take arguments?

Tags: java, macos, command-line-arguments

I have deployed one javaFx app that is basically a command line application on Mac OS X, which take three arguments to run. But with JavaFx I am unable to pass arguments by directly running app, so we need to create one apple script to launch this application.

If I am writing this script -

```
on run argv
    return "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher " & item 1 of argv & " " & item 2 of argv & " " & item 3 of argv & " "
end run
```

This script is not passing parameters to my application.

My requirement is that I have to launch my application at Terminal with three arguments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem, and I think it is a bug in Oracle's JavaAppLauncher.

The more standard and generic way to pass arguments to a bundled application is by using the "open" command:

```
open -a /Applications/MyApp.app --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This command does the right thing for applications built with JarBundler containing JavaApplicationStub, but fails to pass arguments to applications built with Oracle's tools containing JavaAppLauncher.  This was tested with build 1.7.0_45-b18 of Oracle's JRE.